# Brace on(phrase)

Tags: sentence-meaning, phrase-usage

[image]

Let's say a man have successfully survived because:

> He had **braced himself on** the railings before the help arrived.

Compared to:

> He had **held firmly** on the railings before the help arrived.

I know they are not absolutely similar to each other, BUT, is my #1 constructed sentence almost the same in meaning as #2?

[Brace against?](https://www.demilked.com/superhero-bookend-book-hero-supershelf-artori-design/) (kindly check this if my **brace against** analogy is correct)

Comment: Generally speaking, "braced against" is more natural. "He had braced himself *against* the railings before the help arrived."

Comment: braced is more in keeping with the tendency in English to use strong, specific verbs for things. Brace against, yes. [before help arrived, otherwise, it could be the maids.] The help can mean: the hired help.

Comment: The picture does not show that he **held firmly to the railings**, but shows that others **braced him to the railings** with ropes, belts and arms. A common usage for "braced" is "he braced himself for a collision".

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on here, but it looks like a suicide attempt foiled by onlookers who **tied him to the bridge railing with belts and cords** to prevent him from jumping off.

Comment: @Andrew:Let's just assume things happened according to what I have said, not the real incident alike, I need to be proficient in using **’'brace''** only.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Can you see the thicker metal bar on the very top horizontally? Let's say he was holding on it(and not ''to'' the thinner steel rods closest to him) moreover, am I right now to use **brace on**?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: @user3169, Lambie: I know ''brace against'', thx for that, could you click the highlighted link in my question section if I'm correct. I think, according to the picture, ''brace on'' could be used? Hehe

Comment: @JohnArvin  In my mind, when done by a human "brace" suggests a *pushing* action (or a "wedging in place" action) rather than a *pulling* action.  Nothing about this picture suggests *bracing* to me.

Comment: See [*brace*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/brace): "2. *verb* If you brace yourself against something or brace part of your body against it, you press against something in order to steady your body or to avoid falling."

Comment: Hmm thx, I just wanna use the ''brace on'' also that's why. I get it of course, thx

Answer (score 1):

I believe that "held firmly" required ACTIVE muscle strength, compared to "braced" would not require the active muscle strength.  In the case above, the rope/belt is doing the holding, thus bracing the person.

For example.  Trying to hold on to a pipe or rope to keep from falling.  The following item would help someone brace, rather than holding.
https://www.dhresource.com/0x0s/f2-albu-g3-M01-84-93-rBVaHVbOCD6AH5DYAAFOt5siG-U466.jpg/strong-power-weight-lifting-steel-hooks-grips.jpg